# How to avoid and return an event in jquery when you specify a new event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, event-handling

I need to overwrite the events but, the application has an option to return the original events to each element of the document. Any ideas?

For example:

```
    <div class="mydiv">
    </div>

    $(document).delegate( '.mydiv', click', function () { 
        alert('This is the original event my event!');
    });

    $(document).delegate( '.mydiv', 'click', function() {
       alert('Do this and ignore de previous...');
       // For example: How to return the original event when mouseleave event will executed?
    });

    $(document).delegate( '.mydiv', 'mouseleave', function() {
//       return the original event of mydiv 
    });
```

Comment: Why are you assigning multiple `click` events to the same element in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

Use `undelegate function` before creating `new click` function

Docs http://api.jquery.com/undelegate/

Answer (score 0):

try to check click event in functions

$(document).delegate( '.mydiv', click', function ()
 {

```
    if(clicked){
          return;
      }
   alert('This is the original event my event!');

});

$(document).delegate( '.mydiv', 'click', function() {
       if(!clicked){
          return;
      }
   alert('Do this and ignore de previous...');

});
```